# Ansible Lineinfile: Find a key and replace only the value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a .properties/.conf/.xml/.csv files. The requirement is I need to match a key and replace only the value only if that key is present in that file.

My .properties file will look like below,

```
name=newname
surname=newname
```

Below is my key_value.yml file

```
---
properties:
- {  name: name, value: jon}
- { name: surname, value: miller }
```

Below is my ansible task for doing the same.

```
---
- name: Find and replace
  lineinfile:
    dest: /tmp/example/example.properties
    regexp: "{{ item.name }}"
    line: "{{ item.value }}"
    inserafter: '{{ item.name }}='
    backrefs: yes
    state: present
  with_items:
    - "{{ properties }}"
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Its replacing the entire line. Please help!

Comment: Please read the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) carefully. `insertafter` and `line` work not the way you try to use. I think you should opt for [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html) module. And craft the replacement line using backrefs.

Comment: "*a .properties/.conf/.xml/.csv files*" That's far too broad. You won't get a universal task for all the types.

Answer (score -1):

Try including the key in the line:

```
---
- name: Find and replace
  lineinfile:
    dest: /tmp/example/example.properties
    regexp: "{{ item.name }}"
    line: "{{ item.name }}={{ item.value }}"
    backrefs: yes
    state: present
  with_items:
    - "{{ properties }}"
```